# How to link JavaScript to a single onclick action code

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want my site visitors to click on a button and have it open a modal I have created in JavaScript. I copy/pasted the css, html, and js in a single html document and uploaded it to my website's header via a plugin called WP Code Snippets.

This particular WordPress theme allows me to select a button and add a for a JavaScript pop-up window. How do I create an "onclick action link" for the button using the code I've created?

All the code has been completely hacked together. But the modal does work. How can I turn it into an action link?

The code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <section class="modal hidden">

    <div class="flex">
      <button class="btn-close">⨉</button>
    </div>
    <input type=button onClick="location.href='https:www.login.com'" value='Current Clients'>

    <input type=button onClick="location.href='https://www.bookhere.com'" value='New Clients'>

  </section>

  <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
  <button class="btn btn-open">Open Modal</button>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
  const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
  const openModalBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-open");
  const closeModalBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-close");

  // close modal function
  const closeModal = function() {
    modal.classList.add("hidden");
    overlay.classList.add("hidden");
  };

  // close the modal when the close button and overlay is clicked
  closeModalBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
  overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

  // close modal when the Esc key is pressed
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === "Escape" && !modal.classList.contains("hidden")) {
      closeModal();
    }
  });

  // open modal function
  const openModal = function() {
    modal.classList.remove("hidden");
    overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
  };
  // open modal event
  openModalBtn.addEventListener("click", openModal);
</script>
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  }
  
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #222;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #b3e6f4;
  }
  
  .modal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 0.4rem;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 1.3rem;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20%;
    background-color: #c8b490;
    border: 1px solid #c8b490;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  
  .modal .flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .modal input {
    padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #e8e4db;
  }
  
  .modal input:hover {
    background-color: #e8cfaa;
    font-color: #e8e4db;
  }
  
  .modal p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #777;
    margin: 0.4rem 0 0.2rem;
  }
  
  button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #625d5a
  }
  
  .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  
  .btn-open {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px;
  }
  
  .btn-close {
    transform: translate(10px, -20px);
    padding: 0.5rem 0.7rem;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean that you want a sorta toggle-like function? If so, all you need to do is to make a new function called "toggleModal" that checks a boolean to see if it should call openModal, or closeModal.